# cocoa touch -- test if object is an objective-C object

Tags: iphone, c++, cocoa-touch, ios, object

Suppose I have an object.  Might be an objective-C object; might be a C++ object.  Is there a way to test which it is that won't throw any exceptions?

EDIT: I'm happy to use any construct that works, including templates if they will do the job.

Comment: is using @try /@catch an option?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no.  @try/@catch is an objective C construct, and it appears to throw up when given a non-objectiveC object.

Comment: Do you actually have an object, or just a pointer from some source that's erased the type information; that might be either a C++ object's address or some Objective-C object's id?

Comment: I'm using it in multiple ways, all of them related to debugging code.  If I have to track throughout whether my object is Objective C or C++, that's one more thing to keep track of throughout.  Additionally, in some cases the address may come from programmer input, so the programmer would also need to enter whether or not the object is an Objective C object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend found [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html) on the Cocoa with Love blog.  Apparently, the problem is not trivial.

Comment: What about objc_lookUpClass(const char *name) and objc_getClass(const char *name) if you know the name of C++ class? Are C++ classes registered with obj-c runtime when isa implementation is missing from such objects? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use templates, you could do something where you create some type of function that takes a generic template argument, and then instantiate your base-class with all the classes you're using from C++ with a macro.  If it's not a C++ class, then the function returns false.  So for instance:

```
//...in some header file
template<typename T>
bool is_cplusplus(const T* type) { return false; }

#define IS_CPLUSPLUS_T(class) \
           template<> \
           inline bool is_cplusplus(const class* type) { return true; }

//...now use the macro to declare all your C++ classes as "true" in the return 
//from is_cplusplus()
IS_CPLUSPLUS_T(my_class1)
IS_CPLUSPLUS_T(my_class2)

//...now use in some code in a separate .cpp file or .mm file, etc.
my_class1 a_class;
if (is_cplusplus(&a_class))
{
    //do something
}
```

I'm specifically using pointers here rather than references because it's my understanding that you can instantiate a C++ template with a pointer to an Objective-C object, where-as instantiations with Objective-C objects themselves doesn't work.  If this assumption is not correct, then you can make life a little easier by changing from pointers to references.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to enlarge the objects.

Comment: Can you use templates in your solution?  I'm not an Objective-C++ expert, but I do know that many times C++ templates and Objective-C objects don't play nice, so let me know if you can use templates in your solution to at least detect if something is a C++ class ...

Comment: @William Jockusch: Okay, I'm taking another stab at the answer ... hopefully this isn't going to be too cumbersome ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be made a lot simpler than that if the type is available statically (as implied by using a template being an option).  Objective-C objects will be implicitly convertible to NSObject and/or 'id' - C++ objects will not (without at least custom code per class to add the cast operator).

```
// by default, consider it to not be Objective-C.
// C++ object, pointer, built-in, or whatever.
template<typename T>
bool isObjectiveC(const T& ptr) {return false;}
// specialise for any Objective-C object
template<>
bool isObjectiveC(const NSObject*& ptr) {return true;}
template<>
bool isObjectiveC(const id& theID) {return true;}
```

The function prototypes here pass the parameter by `const&` because I've had issues with templating with Objective-C types as returned by Objective-C messages, and this seems to work where plain NSObject* doesn't.